# What's not right in my View and ViewModel code?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I would like to display data in products.xml in the xamDataGrid in MVVM style.Binding is not working properly. Values in the Product node must be added to combo box field in xamDatagrid.

### products.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<WG>
  <WGT>
    <TName>tanme1</TName>
    <Fname>fname1</Fname>
    <Product>Product1</Product>
    <Product>Product2 </Product>
  </WGT>
  <WGT>
    <TName>tanme2</TName>
    <Fname>fname2</Fname>
  </WGT>
  <WGT>
    <TName>tanme1</TName>
    <Fname>fname1</Fname>
    <Product>Product1</Product>
    <Product>Product2 </Product>
    <Product>Product3 </Product>
    <Product>Product4 </Product>
  </WGT>
  <WGT>
    <TName>tanme5</TName>
    <Fname>fname5</Fname>

  </WGT>
  <WGT>
    <TName>tanme1</TName>
    <Fname>fname1</Fname>
    <Product>Product1</Product>
    <Product>Product2 </Product>
    <Product>Product3 </Product>
    <Product>Product4 </Product>
    <Product>Product5 </Product>
    <Product>Product6 </Product>

  </WGT>
</WG>
```

### products.cs [viewModel Class]

```
namespace XmlTest.ViewModel
{
        public partial class WG : ViewBase
    {

        private WGWGT[] itemsField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("WGT", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public WGWGT[] Items
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.itemsField = value;
            }
        }

        public void display()
        {
            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(WG));

            TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\xlf\products.xml");
            object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
            WG XmlData = (WG)obj;
            itemsField = XmlData.Items;



        }
    }

    public partial class WGWGT : ViewBase
    {

        private string tNameField;

        private string fnameField;

        private WGWGTProduct[] productField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string TName
        {
            get
            {
                return this.tNameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.tNameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string Fname
        {
            get
            {
                return this.fnameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.fnameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Product", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = true)]
        public WGWGTProduct[] Product
        {
            get
            {
                return this.productField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.productField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class WGWGTProduct : ViewBase
    {

        private string valueField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
        public string Value
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valueField = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### view.xaml

```
    <Grid>
<igDP:XamDataGrid x:Name="dataGridView1" DataSource="{Binding Items}"  
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="800" Margin="10,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="800">

            <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings >
                <igDP:FieldLayoutSettings AutoGenerateFields="False"/>
            </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>

            <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts >
                <igDP:FieldLayout>
                    <igDP:FieldLayout.Fields >
                        <igDP:Field Label="Template Name" Name="TName" />
                        <igDP:Field Label="File Name" Name="FName"/>


                        <igDP:UnboundField Label="Product Name" >
                            <igDP:UnboundField.Settings>
                                <igDP:FieldSettings EditorType="{x:Type igEditors:XamComboEditor}" AllowEdit="True">
                                    <igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamComboEditor}">
                                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Product}"  />
                                            <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Value" />




                                        </Style>
                                    </igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                                </igDP:FieldSettings>
                            </igDP:UnboundField.Settings>
                        </igDP:UnboundField>
                    </igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
                </igDP:FieldLayout>
            </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
        </igDP:XamDataGrid>
        </Grid>
```

### View.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class View : Window
        {
            public View()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                WaferGen wg = new WaferGen();
                this.DataContext = wg;
                wg.display();
            }
        }
```

Comment: This question is too open-ended... What is the problem here? How is binding not working properly? Please describe in more detail, thanks.

Comment: @TeeSee DataGrid is not displaying the value of TName , Fname and Product

Comment: You not called `display` method, so your ViewModel is empty. Then if you want update UI after `DataContext` was initialized, your viewmodel need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise event when new items is added

Comment: The line `WGWGT[] Items = XmlData.Items;` just initialize new instance of `WGWGT[]`, may be you want change it to `Items = XmlData.Items`

Comment: @Fabio all classes are implementing ViewBase, which in turn has INotifyPropertyChanged event. I forgot to add NotifyPropertyChanged in setter field. Actuallu I have tried with that, did not work. So should I call display() method before setting up datacontext or after?

Comment: @Fabio I have changed it to Items = XmlData.Items , but no luck.

Comment: @Fabio Brilliant. You have nailed it. I  have changed WGWGT[] Items = XmlData.Items to itemsField = XmlData.Items; also called display() method after setting up the datacontext. Thank you very much for your precious time and support.

Comment: @Fabio now I'm trying to display the same in xamDataGrid. I have changed View.xaml. Only the combo box binding not happening properly.Could you help, please?

Comment: Create new question

Comment: @Fabio created a new question. Thanks for the reply.